# How to include pub package path.dart in pubspec.yaml

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am working on an http server POC based on the [route package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route) demo.  It requires the [path package](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/path.html) which states that my `pubspec.yaml` file contain the folowing:

```
name: poc
description: Proof of Concept
dependencies:
  route: any
  path:any
```

The editor marks the word `path` as a reserved word and when I do a `pub get` I get an error

```
Pub get failed, [1] Syntax error on line 5, column 11: invalid YAML in plain scalar
```

which is the line that has the path dependency.  How do I resolve this?

Dart Editor version 1.0.0_r30338 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.0.0.7_r30338

Comment: Could you post your complete pubspec.yaml? But if route uses path, you only need to include path if you want to use it yourself, too.

Comment: @Fox32 Updated to show full pubspec.

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to read the error messages. The answer has already been given to you initially in this message "Syntax error on line 5, column 11: invalid YAML in plain scalar".

Comment: @mezoni That is not an obvious error message to someone not familiar with YAML.  Also, the IDE reported the error on a different line.  I took the time to familiarize myself with YAML and filed two issues with the Dart Editor. https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15333 and https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15328&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: This is just a comment but not answer to your question. And if someone not familiar with YAML nobody forbids to teach it, even superficially. In your example the number of the line reported correctly. This error is a syntax error from YAML parser. Please read this first http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pubspec.html. This is about "pubspec format".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space:

```
 path:any
```

Should be:

```
 path: any
```

I get the same error without a space on any item in the pubspec.yaml

Comment: Such a simple error.  I think I'll post two issues on https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/  One for the syntax highlighting in the editor and another for the obliqueness of the error.

Comment: the IDE does note an error on the *following* line, yes, not the most ideal situation.